# registerForActivityResult and onActivityResult onActivityResult in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload, upload, android-volley

I am currently trying to learn from a step-by-step tutorial to upload an Image or File to my server while using Volley. This tutorial is a little bit outdated and I really don't understand how I can fix these issues.

[the tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-upload-an-image-file-to-your-server-using-volley-in-kotlin-a-step-by-step-tutorial-23f3c0603ec2)

1. `onActivityResult(Int, Int, Intent?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java`
2. `Fragment is attempting to registerForActivityResult after being created. Fragments must call registerForActivityResult() before they are created (i.e. initialization, onAttach(), or onCreate()).`

My code

```kotlin
//Uploading Photos
    private fun launchGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // There are no request codes
                val data: Intent? = result.data
            }
        }
    }

    private fun uploadImage() {
        imageData?: return
        val request = object : VolleyFileUploadRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            postURL,
            {
                println("response is: $it")
            },
            {
                println("error is: $it")
            }
        ) {
            override fun getByteData(): MutableMap<String, FileDataPart> {
                var params = HashMap<String, FileDataPart>()
                params["imageFile"] = FileDataPart("image", imageData!!, "jpeg")
                return params
            }
        }
        Volley.newRequestQueue(requireContext()).add(request)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageData(uri: Uri) {
        val inputStream = requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        inputStream?.buffered()?.use {
            imageData = it.readBytes()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE) {
            val uri = data?.data
            if (uri != null) {
                imageView.setImageURI(uri)
                createImageData(uri)
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to registerForActivityResult from a method "launchGallery()" which is not the way it should be done, "registerForActivityResult" should be initialized in the Activity/Fragment onCreate function and then you can use the "resultLauncher" variable to open the gallery/camera etc...

also when you are using the "registerForActivityResult" you don't need to override "onActivityResult" (which is now deprecated).

check the [Activity Result Api](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) to get a better understanding of how the new api works.

and [here](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-use-the-android-activity-result-api-for-selecting-and-taking-images-5dbcc3e6324b) is a good tutorial that shows you how to use the Android Activity Result API for selecting and taking images